# False Iteration

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration

I want to write a `for` loop that tests two functions on a `list`. First one gives back an int, second a `boolean`. If `boolean == False` the function should remove the element from the list so in the end after calling the function L should have mutated. Here is an example.

```
def f(i):
    return i + 2

def g(i):
    return i > 5

L = [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]

def applyF_filterG(L, f, g):
    for i in L:
        if g(f(i)) == False:        
            L.remove(i)

L = [5, 6]
```

My problem is that with the function written above I get `L = [-10, 5, 6]` back because if `i` is removed, the `i+1` turns into an `i+2` because of the removed element. Does anybody know how to solve this? Big thanks!

Comment: `for i in L` instead of this use `for i in L[:]`, It will iterate though it's copy.

Comment: `[i for i in L if i+2 > 5]` it's also give the same result which you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never remove elements from the list while iterating over it.
just make a new list L1 equal to L and remove elements from L and iterate over L1.

```
def f(i):
    return i + 2

def g(i):
    return i > 5

L = [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]

def applyF_filterG(L, f, g):
    L1 = list(L)
    for i in L1:
        if g(f(i)) == False:        
            L.remove(i)


applyF_filterG( L, f, g )

print L
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you simplify this by just generating another list:

```
L = [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]
r = [a for a in L if a <= 5]
```

or something like that?

Comment: The functions are just examples, they can change. That's why I can't be more specific in the loop

Comment: Then call a function  r = [a for a in L if f(a) <= g()]    It remains the same nevertheless. You need to create a new list instead of deleting items from the list you are looping through. After the loop you can then assign L=r.